# Theano GPU Performance: Difference between theano.shared vs numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, theano-cuda

Several places mention that using shared variables improve performance when using a GPU (like [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/aliasing.html), or [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html)). But I haven't been able to find any numbers quantifying the difference.

Today I was told by a Professor at my school that I am basically wasting my time setting up shared variables, because the speed up in negligible.

Are there any formal tests that you know of, or failing that what are your personal experiences/heuristics?